# What is $ℂ[X]/(X^2+1)$ and why is this not a maxmial ideal.

Tags: ring-theory

This is a passage in a book I'm reading about ring theory:

> The ideal $(X^2+1)$ is maximal in $ℝ[X]$. In $ℂ[X]$ this ideal is not maximal.

I understand that $ℝ[X]/(X^2+1)=ℂ$ therefore it is a field and $I$ must be a maximal ideal. But I don't understand why $ℂ[X]/(X^2+1)$ is not a field. Is this also some special set ?

Comment: Hint: $$\;x^2+1=(x-i)(x+1)\in\Bbb C[x]$$  Then your quotient is the direct product (as rings) of two fields, each isomorphic with $\;\Bbb C\;$ .

Comment: what is $x-i$ times $x+i$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio So $ℂ[X]/(X^2+1)≅ℂ[X]/(X-i) × ℂ[X]/(X+i) ≅ℂ×ℂ$ but is this not a field ?

Comment: @90intuition Right, $\Bbb C\times\Bbb C$ is not a field. Consider $(1,0)\cdot(0,1)=(0,0)$

Comment: Aaah, that is good thing to know !

Answer (score 3):

$\mathbb C[X]/(X^2+1)$ has zero divisors: $(X-i)(X+i)=X^2-i^2=X^2+1=0$. Therefore it cannot be a field.

In ideal language, $(X^2+1)\subsetneq(X+i)\subsetneq (1)$, so $(X^2+1)$ is not a maximal ideal.

---

In general, since $\mathbb C[X]$ is a principal ideal domain and the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra says that any polynomial of degree $\ge 2$ factors, every maximal ideal in $\mathbb C[X]$ must be $(X+c)$ for some $c\in\mathbb C$. But $\mathbb C[X]/(X+c)$ is just $\mathbb C$ itself, so you *cannot* manufacture a proper field extension in this way.

Comment: In other words $ℂ[X]$ is not a domain. So $(X^2+1)$ is not even a prime ideal. Is this right ?

Comment: @90intuition: $\mathbb C[X]$ _is_ an integral domain. It is only its quotient by $(X^2+1)$ that isn't. And no, $(X^2+1)$ is not a prime ideal, by definition since it contains neither $X+i$ nor $X-i$ but does contain their product.

Comment: Oh sorry I meant $ℂ[X]/(X^2+1)$ is not a domain, therefore $(X+2)$ is not a prime ideal.

Comment: *$(X^2+1)$ is not a prime ideal. (fail)

Answer (score 1):

Stated in terms without as much reasoning about fields, the ideal $\langle X^2 + 1 \rangle$ is contained properly in the ideal $\langle X + i \rangle$ when considered as ideals in ${\mathbb C}[X]$. So it's not a maximal ideal, which was the thrust of the original question, and in particular then you can't get a field $\mathbb{C}[X] / \langle X^2 + 1 \rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can think (intuitively) is :

does this generating element can be further factored..

$x^2+1$ can not be factored further in $\mathbb{R}[x]$  where as,

$x^2+1$ can be factored further in $\mathbb{C}[x]$  as $(x+i)(x-i)$

Thus, $(x^2+1)\subsetneq (x+i)$ and  $(x^2+1)\subsetneq (x-i)$

are you familiar with statement for irreducible factorization :

$a=bc$ implies $(a)\subset (b)$ and $(a)\subset (c)$..

If not it would be better to try understand this..